# I'm trying to enable sqlsrv in PHP on my local machine, but it's not showing in php.ini

Tags: php, sql, iis, localhost, sqlsrv

I'm trying to enable sqlsrv in php, i've installed/downloaded the php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.ddl and added it to the extensions in php.ini, resarted iis. When I open phpinfo it doesn't show.

I cannot figure out what's wrong with it.

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL server.

PHP Version = 7.4.6.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what does your http server report upon startup? And... how is php actually integrated into the http server? As a module or as fastcgi container?

Comment: @arkascha it starts up fine, and runs how it should, except from not adding the sqlsrv dll. It's as a fastcgi container.

Comment: What do you see in your server's error log files? Or whatever the replacement is for IIS (which is quite exotic as a web scripting environment...)?

Comment: Also note that there might be several files called `php.ini` or similar due to different usages of the php enfine. Make sure you alter the correct one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to view the real error message when you double click C:\...\PHP\v7.4\PHP_CGI.exe like

[image]

So please check whether your extension_dir are pointing to the right place.

```
  extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.4\ext"
```

And you have put php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll in the ext file.

This is how I register the extension. The driver file must match the PHP version, architecture, and threadedness of your PHP environment.

```
extension=sqlsrv_74_nts_x64
```

You can modify the configurations untill php-cgi.exe no longer report any exception.

Finally the most important thing is run "`IISRESET`" in CMD adminsitrator mode.
Then you will see these extension in phpinfo.

[image]

Please ensure your IIS is mapping to the correct php_cgi.

[image]